# (Error) Sending multiple message to a client through sockets when using serialport

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I have the next problem: I’m trying to send a message to a client using sockets.

First I send a message from an Arduino to nodeJS using the “serialport” library.

Second I send the message that I got from the Arduino to a Web client using socket.io.

The problem comes when I refresh my web page (the client), every time I refresh my web page the socket event “on connection” gets trigger and when node reaches the code where it reads for a message on the serial port and send the message to the client the message is repeated by the number of times that I refreshed my web page.

For example: In the code below if I connect to my web page I will see “Hello world” on the console once, if I refresh the web page I will see “Hello world” twice, and if I refresh a second time I will see “Hello world” three times, one hello world peer page connection/refresh.

So, what I want is to get just one "Hello world" for each socket even when I refresh my page.

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const ReadLine = require('@serialport/parser-readline');
const Express = require('express');
const Socket = require('socket.io');

//Web server
const app = Express();


const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server listening on port 3000");   
});

//Socket web
const io = Socket(server);

const serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", {
    baudRate: 9600 
});
const parser = new ReadLine();

serialPort.pipe(parser);

io.on('connection', function(socketConnection) {
    console.log("New connection"); 

    //Here is the problem
    parser.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("Hello world");

        io.sockets.emit("serverMessage", {
            message: data
        });
    });

});
```

Here is the problem for every time that I connect/refresh node will execute the "console.log()" and the "emit" event the same amount of times.

```
parser.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("Hello world");
    //Here is where i send the message to my client
    io.sockets.emit("serverMessage", {
        message: data
    });
});
```

Here I leave the client code if it helps, but as you can see are just three lines of code.

```
const clientSocket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');


clientSocket.on("serverMessage", function(data) {
    createNewAlert(data.message);         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is caused by triggering multiple listeners...
many listeners is added to [parser.on]
maybe you can add a one-time listener function for the event named parse. The next time eventName is triggered, this listener is removed and then invoked.

```
parser.once('data', (data) => {
    console.log("Hello world");
    //Here is where i send the message to my client
    io.sockets.emit("serverMessage", {
        message: data
    });
});
```